# Any way to use the Scheduler module with the Bean module?

Tags: blocks

I use the https://drupal.org/project/scheduler module with standar content types.

But I see no integration with the Bean module

Is there any way to use the Scheduler module with the Bean module?

If not, are there any other module for this. I need to set both publishing and unpublishing dates for bean nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheduler,

> ...allows **nodes** to be published and unpublished on specified dates.

As for Bean,

> Bean is an acronym that stands for **Block Entities Aren't Nodes**.

Emphasis mine in both.

So no, you can't use Scheduler with Bean as Bean doesn't use nodes. There's no such concept as "bean nodes".

I doubt you'll find a pre-built module with arbitrary scheduling for any type of entity. Being 'published' is a concept specific to the node entity type; not all entity types have that characteristic, so I doubt you'll find anything generic.

You'll probably need to write something from scratch. The code for scheduler will be the best starting point, but it'll need to be adapted to work with entities (or at least the Bean entity type).

Comment: I know this is out the scope of the question but... Should I give a try to the http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock module to use it to create blocks from nodes? I mean, should I use nodeblock instead of bean to create blocks?